# root-n consistency of penalized M-estimator with fixed p

Tags: lasso, regularization, consistency, m-estimation

I am trying to find conditions for the root-n consistency of a generic L1-penalized M-estimator in a fixed p setting. I was able to find those for L1-penalized likelihood and regression (Fan, Li (2001)) and for my case but with diverging p (Negahban et al., 2012). In the latter in particular they state that in the fixed p setting there are standard techniques for proving consistency, but they don’t cite anyone on this. Could anyone give me some pointers on where to find these techniques? Thanks!

Comment: If your loss function is still convex, as it is if you are using for example a residual sum of squares plus a penalization term involving the L1 norm, then you can use standard results such as Theorem 3.1 in Newey and McFadden (1994). If your loss function is not twice continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of the true parameter, then you might want to consult Theorem 3.3 in Pakes and Pollard (1989).

- NF (1994): https://doi.org/10.1016/S1573-4412(05)80005-4
- PP (1989): https://www.jstor.org/stable/1913622

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks to me like Theorem 3.1 in NF (1994) already needs consistency to begin with, am I missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It does indeed! Don't you have it in your setting?

Comment: Yes, you’re right, that already comes with the fact that the penalty parameter goes to 0 as n increases, for any consistent M-estimator. For some reason I was thinking I had to prove that too. Thank you!